# How do you get the subjectAltName from a CSR in php?

Tags: php, openssl, csr

The php reference has functions like [openssl_csr_get_subject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-get-subject.php), but how do I get the subjectAltNames from the csr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that its possible, I instead went with [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to do this for me.

Comment: Hi, do you sample working code on this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try `openssl_x509_parse` alternative subjects can read as extensions, I believe you will find:

```
[extensions][subjectAltName] => DNS:*.cacert.org, DNS:cacert.org, DNS:*.cacert.net, DNS:cacert.net, DNS:*.cacert.com, DNS:cacert.com
```

Comment: thats a nice thought, but that only works with full x509 certs, not csr's.