# Display subjectAltName from a CSR in php

Tags: php, openssl, phpseclib, csr

I got an issue on my end while displaying the CSR Subject Alternative Name using PHP. I run some research and found some interesting, but the problem is that, it was 10 years ago and no code for reference. Here is the link: [How do you get the subjectAltName from a CSR in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982778/how-do-you-get-the-subjectaltname-from-a-csr-in-php)

The library is [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/csr). It has documentation related to CSR but don't know how to use such library. Do you have idea on how to use the library and display the Subject Alternative Name?. I'm not good at coding using libraries. Really appreciate any help. Been searching for 2 days.

Comment: Check out their updated documentation: https://phpseclib.com/docs/csr

Comment: Take a CSR that has subjectAltName, do `$csr = $x509->loadCSR(file_get_contents('csr.csr'));` and then do `print_r($csr)` and you can see where it is that way.

Comment: @neubert. I'm having another issue in which my  `phpseclib\File\X509;` not found. Here is my complete code.

`<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\File\X509;

$x509 = new X509();
$csr = $x509->loadCSR(file_get_contents('myscr.csr'));
var_dump($x509);`

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you using? If you're using v3 then you should be doing `use phpseclib3\File\X509;` If you're using v2 and that's your code then I'd double check your vendor directory to make sure that phpseclib is even in there.

Comment: This works. Last question, how do I get the property in this array?

Comment: I tried to use this `print_r($x509->getMapping('id-ce-subjectAltName'));` but got error of `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private method phpseclib3\File\X509::getMapping() from global scope`

Comment: @lothux1987 - try `$x509->getExtension('id-ce-subjectAltName')`. Also, try doing `@neubert` next time - asis I didn't get a notification that you had replied. You get a notification without me doing that because I'm responding to your post. I don't get said notification, however, because, when the `@whomever` isn't present stackoverflow assumes that you're replying to the post - not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @neubert for the answer that I needed, I also want to share this to anyone has the same issue as mine.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib3\File\X509;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSR Decode</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #333333;
        }
        table.section{width:100%;}
        table.ftable td{padding:0px;text-align:center;font-size:13px;}
        h3{
            color: #2e6da4;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        table{
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th, td{
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            font-size:15px;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even){
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        img{
             width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table.table td{border:none;}
                table.table{border:none;}
    input[type="text"] {width: 30%;padding: 5px 20px;border:1px solid white;}
        input[type="submit"]{
            width: 16%;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            background-color:#67BC5A;
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
            border:1px solid #67BC5A;
            border-radius:5px;}
    form.form {padding-bottom: 20px;}


    p {
        display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .csr_info {
        display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }

    .csr_info > ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    .csr_info > ul > li{
        background: url(./img/check.png) no-repeat left;
        font-size: 14px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 20px 0 0px 58px;
    margin: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 4px;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="ftable" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
    <td  style="border:none;">
    <h3>Decode CSR</h3>
    <form class="form"action="" method="POST">
        <div>
            <textarea name="csr" rows="22" cols="99"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Decode CSR">
        </div>
    </form>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $csr = $_POST['csr'];
  $x509 = new X509();
  $csr2 = $x509->loadCSR($csr);
?>
<p>CSR Information</p>
<div class="csr_info">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <strong>Common Name</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('CN'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>
    <li>
            <strong>Subject Alternative Name:</strong>:
      <?php
        $ext = array_values($x509->getExtension('id-ce-subjectAltName'));
        foreach ($ext as $value) {
          $san = array_values($value);
          echo " , " .$san[0];
        }
      ?>
        </li>
    <li>
            <strong>Organization</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('O'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Organization Unit</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('OU'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Locality</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('L'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>State</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('ST'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Country</strong>:
      <?php
        $result = array_values($x509->getDNProp('C'));
        echo $result[0];
      ?>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```